# How to Loading BAG file format in QGIS

Tags: qgis, bathymetry

I need to load a BAG file (Bathymetry attributed grid) in QGIS (3.4) according to the supported file page https://www.gdal.org/formats_list.html it is supported, but is not compiled by default and requires "libhdf5" I have no idea what this means, is there a plugin I need to install or do I need to compile something my self? I have no programming experience, so compiling software myself is not an option.

Answer (score 1):

Both QGIS 3.4.5 Long Term Release (LTR) and 3.6 can open BAG files from `Data Source Manager -> Raster`

In QGIS 3.6:

[image]

In QGIS 3.4.5 (LTR)

[image]

Comment: I did see this but get the following error when loading a BAG file. Invalid Layer : GDAL provider Cannot open GDAL dataset K:/4.Basemap Database/1.National/BAGS/Glencairn_0.5m.bag:
             `K:/4.Basemap Database/1.National/BAGS/Glencairn_0.5m.bag' not recognized as a supported file format.

Comment: I think the problem is not in BAG files but in the path of your filenames. You have periods `.` in the bath after each number which is not acceptable. You need to change the `.` into underscore `_` and see if the file can be opened.

Comment: I copied the file to a local drive with no ".", got the same error. I did manage to load the raster by dragging the *.bag.ovr file into the project, but the .ovr is the overview as far as I know, and they do not plot spacially correct. This is the same for all bag files I have. They do load correctly in AcrMap.

Comment: I have the same problem loading .bag files at 2.18.28 and 3.8.3.  Just like you, I could load them in Arc Desktop 10.7.1.  My solution was to save the .bag files to .tif in Arc and then load the .tifs in QGIS.  I'm brand new to .bag files, so I'm not sure if this is the appropriate method.  Could this be a QGIS error?